# Flutter TextField with IconButton

Tags: flutter

I have two problems with this widget. When adding the `suffix: IconButton...` it adds what looks like a padding inside the textfield. And how can I show the suffix icon when _searchController.text is not empty. I tried `_searchController.text != null ? IconButton(...): 'not sure what to return here'`

```
  Widget _searchBox() {
    return TextField(
      controller: _searchController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Search",
        hintText: "Search",
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        suffix: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () => _searchController.clear(),
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

With suffix:

[image]

Withoug suffix:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using ideas from both answers. One didn't explain how to show and hide the icon while the other seemed a bit too complicated. All I did is `_searchController.text.isEmpty`

```
  Widget _searchBox() {
    return TextField(
      controller: _searchController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Search",
        hintText: "Search",
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        suffixIcon: _searchController.text.isEmpty
            ? null
            : InkWell(
                onTap: () => _searchController.clear(),
                child: Icon(Icons.clear),
              ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can use IconButton in place of InkWell: it has an icon, and an action, it's simpler and more suited for this job ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use suffixIcon instead. To update the icon depending on the state you need to call setState somewhere.

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _SearchWidgetState createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget> {
  String _searchText = "";
  TextEditingController _searchController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return TextField(
        controller: _searchController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Search",
          hintText: "Search",
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),

          suffixIcon: _searchText.isNotEmpty ? IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear),onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _searchController.clear();
            });},) : null,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchController = TextEditingController();
    _searchController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _searchText = _searchController.text;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
      _searchController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Edit: don't forget to dispose

Comment: calling setState() inside the listener controller will make all the widgets inside the build to be refreshed. Without it the clear icon will no update when the text is entered. Did you know a way to only update the TextFiled that have changed?

Comment: I am not sure but as per my understanding, creating a separate widget for textfield with Icons can help. Because in that way on that widget would get rebuild and not the other widgets.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Widget _searchBox() {
    return TextField(
      controller: _searchController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Search",
        hintText: "Search",
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),

        suffix: InkWell(

          child: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () => _searchController.clear(),
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Using a 'suffix icon' instead of 'suffix' would solve the issue with alignment. SuffixIcon doesn't affect the hint text.